# How to get 'parked location' information of Apple Maps's 'find my car' in iOS 10

Tags: ios, maps, ios10, apple-maps

iOS 10 Apple Map has 'show parked location' and I like this feature.

I want to make app for history of my parked locations, but I can't find APIs for that.

How to get information of parked location which is controlled by Apple Maps?

or How to implement this feature by own not by Apple Maps?

[image]

Comment: I also need this information. If anyone have?

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try and query the motion framework for all recent motion activities using [CMMotionActivityQueryHandler](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager/1615929-queryactivitystarting) then get all the recent [CLVisit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clvisit) objects through CLLocationManger, correlate the data and figure out where the user was when he stopped being in a car.

It won't be perfect, it won't be the same as the Apple Maps one and it depends on whether people have Frequent Locations enabled (they mostly do, they're on by default), but it's the next best thing.